# Java Mockito - How to test a method which is calling a method in the same class as well as a method from other class?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, spy

I have the code structure like this. Method `methodToTest` in `ClassA` is calling a method in `ClassA` as well well as a method in `ClassB`

```
public class ClassA {
    @Autowired
    ClassB classB;

    public void methodToTest() {
        Object c = methodInA();
        Object d = classB.methodInB(c);
    }

    public Object methodInA() {
        //do something
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    public Object methodInB(Object obj) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I was trying to mock both calls i.e. call to `methodInA` and to `methodInB`

Following is the unit-test code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ClassATest {
    @InjectMocks
    ClassA classA;

    @Mock
    ClassB classB;

    @Spy
    ClassA classASpy;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    //Test method in ClassA
    @Test
    public void testMethodInA() {
        Object mockObjA = mock(Object.class);
        Object mockObjB = mock(Object.class);

        doReturn(mockObjA).when(classASpy).methodInA();
        when(classB.methodInB(mockObjA)).thenReturn(mockObjB);

        classA.methodToTest();

        //assertions
    }

}
```

On running the test, `Object c` is null but I want it to be equal to `mockObjA`.

I tried invocation with `classASpy.methodToTest()` also from the test. But then it gives `NullPointerException` at line `Object d = classB.methodInB(c)` in `methodToTest()`.

What will be the correct way to test such scenario?

Comment: Using Mockito annotations require either the Mockito runner or the appropriate rule or an initMocks call, see the doc: http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock_annotation

Comment: I have updated the test code. I am using initMocks in setup method. I missed to mention it here.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: write a test for `methodInA` and then simply write a test for `methodToTest` without worrying about `methodInA`?

Answer (score 2):

When you are invoking `methodToTest` you are testing the unit `ClassA`. It doesn't make much sense to alter the unit under test by mocking something of that unit. Because then you would test something completely different then `ClassA`.

What you should do is to test that `classB.methodInB` is invoked with the correct argument. You do this by using an [`ArgumentCaptor`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) for the argument of invocation `classB.methodInB`.

```
ArgumentCaptor<Object > argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object .class);
verify(mockObjB).methodInB(argument.capture());
Object capturedArgument = argument.getValue();
```

Then you make assertions on `capturedArgument` that verify that `ClassA.methodInA` worked correctly.

Comment: but then i will have to mock all the external method calls invoked in `methodInA()`, in every test for method that is using `methodInA()`

Comment: @msfk if `methodInA` is really that complex then it is possible that `ClassA` doesn't stick to the single responsibility principle. If that is the case extracting `methodnInA` to its own interface may make sense. Then you also would be able to mock the call to `methodInA`.

Comment: I separated out a helper class from the actual class and move the methods as public to the helper class. Is this a good practice?